# SimpleMember User Account Creation with T-SQL - How are the passwords hashed?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, simplemembership

Can Simple Membership user accounts be created from SQL Server Management Studio?

The only methods I have found for User/Account creation are in C# when running a application:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("userName", "password",
                        new
                        {
                            ...
                        }, false);
```

Is there any way to generate a hashed password that can be used in Simple Membership with t-SQL? Are the requirements for a Simple Membership hashed password known? I have found other methods for generating the password with the DefaultMembershipProvider, but the passwords are not compatible with Simple Membership.

EDIT:
I was hoping to find a process similar to this:

```
declare @salt nvarchar(128)
declare @password varbinary(256)
declare @input varbinary(512)
declare @hash varchar(64)

-- Change these values (@salt should be Base64 encoded)
set @salt = N'eyhKDP858wdrYHbBmFoQ6DXzFE1FB+RDP4ULrpoZXt6f'
set @password = convert(varbinary(256),N'mypassword')

set @input = hashbytes('sha1',cast('' as  xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(''@salt''))','varbinary(256)') + @password)
set @hash = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable(''@input'')))','varchar(64)')
```

that could be used for Simple Membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create then import a simple .NET assembly and use it in Sql Server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx

Membership Services use configurations of system and encryption libraries of .NET to generate one-way hashes AFAIK, so it would  not be trivial to redo the same thing in t-sql.